# How can I generate sequence diagrams from a big Java Project

Tags: java, plugins, diagram, sequential

I am just looking for a open-source software or plug-ins implemented for NetBeans or eclipse to generate sequential diagram for a big project. I know there are some software doing this issue such as MajicDraw, Visual Paradiam. Moreover, I know there is one plug-ins for NetBeans and one for eclipse, but they just generate sequence diagram for one class not for a big project.

Comment: I can safe you a lot of work and disappointment: don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequence diagrams describe a runtime view, that cannot be captured by static code analysis. There are some runtime tools, e.g. dynatrace, that can display sequence diagrams. However, one of the most important things when creating a sequence diagram, is deciding what to display and what to ignore, a job that a tool can hardly do. If you do not filter accordingly the diagram can become very large and probably quite useless.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment. In fact , I am looking for a software or pulg-ins to show me the call hierarchy in a java project because after that I can see which functions never invoked and so I have this chance to remove these unused functions from my peoject.